# How can I protect my horse from a dog while I am riding?

Tags: dogs, behavior, horses, large-dogs

Assuming I am riding, and a dog starts attacking my horse, what are the best ways to stop the attack?

I would prefer a solution that does not require me to dismount, since my horse and the dog might just run off in a chase. Are there things I could carry on me to help? Something I can always do? Is "running away" possible - will the dog give up a chase?

Comment: Advice of my riding teacher was always to shout loud and blame the dog while riding in a confronting way to the dog. But I was never in this situation, so I do not know how helpful this is from own experience. Without horse blustering a small dog was successful, it went back to it's own yard, where the door was not closed properly. As very last action I would think about hitting it with the whip. Some horses would also try to hit it with the hoove I assume.

Comment: Depends on the dog and horse. I would let my horse attack the dog in defense, I doubt a dog would dare to attack it, anyway. Another tactic could be to intentionally try to ride over the dog. A horse (usually) is way bigger than a dog, this mass can be put to good use in defense. Both tactics, though, include risking to injure and kill the dog, which, in my opinion is justified as an attacking dog risks the victim's death, either. Solution would require your horse to have a minimum of self-esteem.